# java -cp issues with different files location

Tags: java, scala, classpath

I'm unable to access the property value of a properties file from the scala class.

I have tried to load the properties using the below statements:
#config is defined inside other class

```
lazy val config = ConfigFactory.load()
lazy val brokers = config.getString("property_name")
```

Here i'm running this java -cp command in edgenode:

`java -cp /fullpath/jar_name.jar:/full_path/application.properties` classname parameters

I tried to place both the `jar` & `application.properites` files in same location and if i pass as below it is working:

I tried to pass two different location files one is jar & other one is properties file as part of class path. But it is not picking up the properties file if i pass as below:

```
java -cp .:*  classname parameters
```

Hope it clears. Please do suggest here.Thanks

Comment: Which operating system are you using ?

Comment: I"m using linux operationg system in the server

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're using the Lightbend Config library. To specify where to load the configuration from, you need to set the `config.file` JVM property.
https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior

The easiest way to do that is to add `-Dconfig.file=path/to/the/file` to the JVM flags. Note that the path should not include the file extension.